# What specific lighting property creates "the unity look"

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders, shading

Nearly all unity games have specific "unity" look. It is quite obvious that it is caused by the rendering pipeline and shading, but I was wondering which specific part is responsible for that and if there is a way to change it.

Edit: As per request a few references (subnautica and two point campus):
[image: Subnautica interior]

[image: two point campus zoom]

I chose 2 premium indie games, to show that this is not a simple case of "spend money on resources/modelling scrub", but most likely some property of rendering engine. All the surfaces and models seem to have this... plastic(?) look? The point of this post in a way is to point out what exactly is causing this.

Comment: Can you show a few examples of what you've identified as "the Unity look", or a screenshot of your own game in progress with commentary about what you find unsatisfactory about the current appearance? This can help focus answers on identifying and suggesting fixes for the right root causes to address your needs.

Comment: @DMGregory added a few examples

Comment: It seems to me that it is a matter of shaders and post processing.

Comment: It this the glossy look that a lot of people usually see as "cheap". It is often overused because it is good for showing the shape/texture of the surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't say that there is a universal "Unity look"; see games like *Cities: Skylines*, *Battletech*, *Dave the Diver*, and *Mechanicus* for examples of different visual styles in 3D Unity games.

The "plastic" look you are seeing is caused by giving a material a medium-to-high amount of smoothness and not assigning a specular map or normal map.

The standard shader in Unity is a Physically Based Rendering (PBR) shader. Without getting into too much detail about the nature of PBR, one of the characteristics is a 'smoothness' setting that defines how glossy the surface is (some renderers invert this value and call it "roughness" instead).

With a very simple Standard Shader setup, the material might only have an albedo texture (defining the color of the material) and a fixed value for Smoothness (in range 0 - 1 where 0 is not glossy at all and 1 is fully glossy). This gives the entire material a uniform level of smoothness/glossiness...

[image: Cylinder with smoothness of 0.75]

...which looks unrealistic. But why?

Here's a photo of one of my tablets. The screen certainly isn't uniform in glossiness, and probably hasn't been since the day I took it out of the box. There's dust and smudged finger oils all over the screen.

[image]

Using the Standard Shader in Unity, we can create this kind of look using a Specular Map or Metallic Map with an alpha channel. With this setup, the alpha channel defines the Smoothness, or glossiness, of the surface, meaning it doesn't have to be uniform over the entire surface.

Here's the same cylinder with a simple Specular Map added to make the smoothness of the material non-uniform. Now the cylinder looks like it's got smudges or other wear on the surface, which looks much more realistic:

[image: Cylinder with Specular map]

The alpha channel of the Specular map looks like this. The brightness corresponds to glossiness of the surface, where black is no gloss and white is full gloss.

[image]

Specular maps aren't only used to make glossy surfaces look smudged. They can also be used for effects like making part of a rough surface (such as a stone) look like it's been worn smooth, or to make it look as if paint has been scratched and worn off of the corners of metallic objects.

Of course, in reality, most surfaces besides polished glass have some texture to them. In video games, we often add texture to a surface with Normal Maps, which are special textures which alter the direction of a surface for lightning calculations. Normal maps (sometimes referred to in slang as "bump maps") can add a lot of realism to a surface without increasing the polygon count.

Here's our cylinder with a Normal Map added to give it a brushed-metal look:

[image: Cylinder with specular and normal maps]

The example screenshots you shared don't appear to make use of Specular or Normal maps, which is why the surfaces have that artificially smooth look.

Comment: I'd suggest a lack of global illumination or using the default skybox for directional ambient light may also be a factor.

Comment: I would actually say that Cities Skylines (at least the first one) exemplifies the Unity look, but i accepted this as the answer nonetheless.